# Documentation with some text highlighted in gray

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, code-documentation

The option to document functions in Julia is straightforward, which is welcoming. Is it possible to have certain keywords in the documentation highlighted when using a Jupyter notebook?

For e.g.

```
"""
function ph(phoenix_one, phoenix-two)

      phoenix_one is an array of tuples containing information on height and weight, and phoenix-two contains position data.
"""
function ph(phoenix_one, phoenix-two)
    return phoenix_one + phoenix-two
end
```

when `?ph` is called

The expectation is:

`phoenix_one` is an array of tuples containing information on height and weight, and `phoenix-two` contains position data.

instead of

phoenix_one is an array of tuples containing information on height and weight, and phoenix-two contains position data.

That is with some keywords highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do it (use backticks + note the layout of the docstring)

```
"""
    ph(phoenix_one, phoenix_two)

`phoenix_one` is an array of tuples containing information on height and weight,
and phoenix-two contains position data.
"""
function ph(phoenix_one, phoenix_two)
    return phoenix_one + phoenix_two
end
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this in a Jupyter notebook but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to show you how to do it and prove that it works.

Comment: Do I need to use some additional package to make this happen? I am using Julia 1.0.3

Comment: Try running it in JuliaBox. I have just checked and it works as above (you can also check the used nbextensions in the last tab). How do you start Jupyter? A normal way is running `using IJulia` and then `notebook()`.